# Intermittent errors with object being included in NavPush on Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to build an interaction where I go from a profile page to a separate edit profile page by pushing it and including the profile to be edited. However, I'm intermittently getting a `TypeError` saying the app can't find elements expected within the `profile` object being passed.

Here is the full error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'about_me' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'about_me' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/EditProfilePage.ngfactory.js:510:34)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15003:21)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14172:14)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14522:21)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14454:13)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14178:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15404:42)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14941:12)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11964:18)
    at Tab.NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:50138:40)
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
    at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19174)
    at Tab.NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:49901:16)
    at Tab.NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:49894:14)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:49941:59
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5293:33)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
```

This is the html element on the profile page:

```
<button class="edit-profile" *ngIf="isCurrentUser" ion-item (click)="editProfile(profile)" detail-none><ion-icon name="create-outline"></ion-icon> Edit Profile</button>
```

This is the method:

```
editProfile(person: Person) {
  this.navCtrl.push(EditProfilePage, person);
}
```

And this is the component of the edit profile page:

```
export class EditProfilePage {

  profile: Person;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.profile = navParams.data;
    console.log(navParams.data);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad EditProfilePage');
    console.log(this.profile);
  }

}
```

Comment: show the complete error message and in which line

Comment: added to the original post

Comment: where you're using `about_me`?

Comment: Here: 

    `<ion-item>
      <ion-label class="profile-about-me" stacked>About Me</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="profile.about_me"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>`

Comment: ` console.log(navParams.data);` shows undefined ?

Comment: show how you fill profile object  in profile page

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it says undefined other times it gives me the actual profile instance.

This is what I do in the profile page: 

  `getCurrentUser(): void {
    this.usersService.getMe()
        .subscribe(
          response => {
            this.profile = response.results[0];
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
          })
  }`

Comment: see the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the profile if it's not undefined

```
editProfile(person: Person) {
   if(person)
     this.navCtrl.push(EditProfilePage, person);
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is working, appreciate the help. Do you know why I might be getting this error? What might be causing the profile object to not get passed sometimes?

Comment: I have no idea  May be `this.usersService.getMe()` take some time to bring data and you click the button before the profile is filled